Baum-Welch algorithm for non-unique sequences
I am currently performing a hidden Markov model over multiple sequences. However, many of these sequences are the same. Because of this, I found that the Baum-Welch algorithm should be adjusted to account for this:
$  \hat{\pi}_i = \frac{\sum_{r=1}^R \gamma_{ir}(0)}{R}= \frac{\sum_{s\in S}  N_s \gamma_{is}(0)}{R}$
$        \hat{a}_{ij} = \frac{\sum_{r=1}^{R} \sum_{t=0}^{T-2} \xi_{ijr}(t)}{\sum_{r=1}^{R} \sum_{t=0}^{T-2} \gamma_{ir}(t)}
    = \frac{\sum_{s \in S}  N_s \sum_{t=0}^{T-2}\xi_{ijs}(t)}{\sum_{s \in S} N_s \sum_{t=0}^{T-2} \gamma_{is}(t)}
    $
$   \hat{b}_{ij} = \frac{\sum_{r=1}^{R} \sum_{t=0}^{T-1} 1_{\{O_{tr} = j \}} \gamma_{ir}(t)}{\sum_{r=1}^{R} \sum_{t=0}^{T-1} \gamma_{ir}(t)} = \frac{\sum_{s \in S} N_s \sum_{t=0}^{T-1} 1_{\{O_{ts} = j \}} \gamma_{is}(t)}{\sum_{s \in S} N_s \sum_{t=0}^{T-1} \gamma_{is}(t)}
 $
Here, $R$ is the total number of sequences, $s \in S$ a unique sequence and $N_s$ is corresponding count. This should, especially in my case reduce the calculation time.
However, I did not yet find any literature or a package that does this? Does anyone know whether this exists?
